# Title of novel: mass murderer, enshrouded planet, dead civilization, female military captain

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel roughly about 25 years ago. What I remember is that the protagonist was a mass murderer and he ended up on a planet on which the civilization was gone, but their buildings and machinery remained. I remember he used one piece of machinery to generate his dead wife to talk to. I remember the planet was enshrouded, making it difficult to be spotted by starships. And I remember a military starship spotted the planet anyway, and landed. The Captain of the starship was female.

Comment: You have a nice start here but can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: Based on the title, I was thinking Vorkosigan, but the body does not match.